Add auth to FastAPI via Middleware and include in OpenAPI
Basic goal: A means of authenticating most (but not all) routes in one place (a separate file), seamlessly so that I don't have to add code/documentation to every one of the routes in order to get auth or openapi to work.
I would like to implement a basic Bearer Authorization in FastAPI, but do so in class-based middle-ware. I've done this successfully, but I have not seen how to do this in a way that OpenAPI is aware of it (ie. there's no way to set auth tokens in the docs)
class AuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    async def __call__(self, request: Request, call_next):
        if self.is_protected_url(request.method, request.url.path):
            auth = request.headers.get("Authorization")
            scheme, data = (auth or " ").split(" ", 1)
            if scheme != "Bearer":
                return JSONResponse(None, 401, {"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"})
            if data != self.settings.auth_token:
                return JSONResponse(None, 401, {"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"})

        return await call_next(request)

    def is_protected_url(self, method, url):
        """ does what it does """

In the main file:
from path.to.auth import AuthMiddleware

auth_middleware = AuthMiddleware(settings)
app.middleware("http")(auth_middleware)

There seem to some existing auth classes to use, but I can't figure out how to properly get them to work in a class-based Middleware that is in a separate file (Depends doesn't resolve).
See

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74088523
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107848
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007
https://github.com/florimondmanca/awesome-asgi?tab=readme-ov-file#authentication
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/reference/security/#fastapi.security.APIKeyCookie--example


this might help https://medium.com/@chandanp20k/leveraging-custom-middleware-in-python-fastapi-for-enhanced-web-development-09ba72b5ddc6

Have two APIRouters on the root level - one for authenticated routes and one for those without. Import OAuth2PasswordBearer - from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, and add it as a default dependency to the API router that handles your routes that require authentication. Add any routes (or other routers) under that specific router. FastAPI's built-in openapi generator will know about this class and add the proper information (and send authentication) when you use that class. See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/#update-the-dependencies
